# use a combobox selection for linq query

Tags: wpf, linq, combobox

I have a combobox that gets populated from a database table.  When the combobox is diplayed in the window it has the StationName, but it also has a "hidden" value for a StationId.  Here is how I get the combobox to display the choices:

```
StationBox.ItemsSource = dc.WasteTrackerStations;
```

How can I get to that StationId property to use that in a seperate query to populate a datagrid?  This is the code for my SelectionChanged event:

```
private void StationBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var miquery = from mi in dc.WasteTrackerDBs
                      where mi.StationId == [this value needs to be StationId from combobox selection]
                      select new
                      {
                          mi.MenuItem,
                          mi.LeftOver,
                          mi.Par,
                          mi.UoM,
                          mi.StationId
                      };
        EWDataGrid.ItemsSource = miquery;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComboBox has `SelectedItem` property. It will be an element of `dc.WasteTrackerStations` collection (or `null`). Cast it to concrete type and all properties will be accessible:

```
private void StationBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var item = StationBox.SelectedItem as WasteTrackerStation;
    if (item == null) return;
    var selectedStationId = item.StationId;

    var miquery = from mi in dc.WasteTrackerDBs
                  where mi.StationId == selectedStationId
                  select new
                  {
                      mi.MenuItem,
                      mi.LeftOver,
                      mi.Par,
                      mi.UoM,
                      mi.StationId
                  };
    EWDataGrid.ItemsSource = miquery;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ASh, worked like a charm, I was missing the step of casting